# How to get last day of previous month in Impala?

Tags: sql, impala

I'd like to get the **last day of previous month** in Impala as any type (preferably string).

It should be well **readable** and **effective**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the day of month from today and you get the last day of the previous month:

```
date_sub(now(), day(now())
```

This includes the current time.

To get midnight you can truncate it to the begin of month and subtract one day:

```
date_sub(trunc(now(), 'month'), 1)
```

Both result in timestamp, but can be easily casted to a string.

Comment: @jirislav: No, just too simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Using the *regexp*

```
SELECT 
    days_sub(
        regexp_replace( 
            regexp_extract(
                cast(now() AS string),
                '[\\d-]{10}',
                0
            ), /* Get today in format: YYYY-mm-dd */
            '\\d{2}$', '01'
        ), /* Get the first day of this month: YYYY-mm-01 */
        1
    ) /* Subtract one day */
    AS DAY
```

**One liner**

```
SELECT days_sub(regexp_replace(regexp_extract(cast(now() AS string), '[\\d-]{10}', 0),'\\d{2}$', '01'), 1) AS DAY
```

---

## Using the *extract* & *concat* functions

```
SELECT 
    days_sub(
            concat(
                cast(extract(now(),'year') AS string), /* Extract current year*/
                '-',
                regexp_replace(
                    cast(extract(now(),'month') AS string), /* Extract current month */
                    '^\\d$', '0\\0'
                ), /* Make sure the month has two digits e.g. from '1' create '01' */
                '-01'
            ),  /* Concat current year, month and day one */
            1 
        ) /* Subtract one day */
        AS DAY
```

**One liner**

```
SELECT days_sub(concat(cast(extract(now(),'year') AS string), '-', regexp_replace(cast(extract(now(),'month') AS string), '^\\d$', '0\\0'), '-01'), 1) AS DAY
```

---

## Comparison

Both options result in the same result of type `TIMESTAMP`:

```
2017-06-30 00:00:00
```

It can be casted to string easily by using `cast(result as string)`

The **regexp** way seems to be more readable to me, so I'm using that version.